# C# Database Converting Time to DateTime

Tags: c#, database, datetime, visual-studio-2013, time

So I have a table in visual studios with a field that has time(7) as its datatype

Then I have a form with a datagridview that is supposed to read the table and show the records. However, I cannot figure out how to read the Time as there is no GetTime function, and cant find a way to convert it to DateTime.
The current setup:

```
public Periods getPeriodsFromReader(SqlDataReader reader)

    {
        Periods newPeriod = new Periods();
        newPeriod.PeriodId = reader.GetInt32(0);
        newPeriod.StartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetDateTime(1));
        return newPeriod;
    }
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to get the time from the database so I can put it on the datagridview?

Comment: Can you show us how the value looks like?